# Looking for function or formula to create table with means and standard deviations for many groups and many variables using tidyverse

Tags: r, iteration, tidyverse

I need to prepare a table that includes the means and standards deviations for each level of several demographic variables and for many variables.

Consider the following data:

```
df <- tibble(place=c("London","Paris","London","Rome","Rome","Madrid","Madrid"),gender=c("m","f","f","f","m","m","f"), education = c(1,1,2,3,5,5,3), var1 = c(2.2,3.1,4.5,1,5,1.4,2.3),var2 = c(4.2,2.1,2.5,4,5,4.4,1.3),var3 = c(0.2,0.1,3.5,3,5,2.4,4.3))
```

I would like to get a dataframe that contains the **grouping variables** (place, gender, education) and their levels (e.g., London, Paris, etc.) **in the first column** and their means and standard deviations for each variable starting with var (var1, var2, var3) in additional columns.

I know how to do this for one group and several variables at a time. However, since I need to repeat this dozens of times I am looking for a way to automate this process. It would be great to have a **function to which I simply need to pass (a) the names of the grouping variables (e.g., gender, education) and (b) the variables from which to get the M / SD (e.g. var1, var2).**

The solution I look for should look like this (the stats are not correct in the example below):

```
my_results <- tibble(grouping_vars = c("place_London","place_Paris","place_Rome","place_Madrid","gender_m","gender_f","last_element"),mean_var1=c(1.3,2.5,4.5,1.7,2.5,3.6,4.0),sd_var1=c(0.01,0.41,0.21,0.12,0.02,0.38,0.28),mean_var2=c(4.3,4.5,4.0,1.2,2.5,1.6,2.3),sd_var2=c(0.21,0.1,0.1,0.32,0.22,0.18,0.08),mean_var3=c(2.3,2.5,2.0,3.2,3.5,0.6,5),sd_var3=c(0.51,0.15,0.51,0.52,0.52,0.15,0.48))

  grouping_vars  mean_var1 sd_var1 mean_var2 sd_var2 mean_var3 sd_var3
  <chr>              <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 place_London         1.3    0.01       4.3    0.21       2.3    0.51
2 place_Paris          2.5    0.41       4.5    0.1        2.5    0.15
3 place_Rome           4.5    0.21       4      0.1        2      0.51
4 place_Madrid         1.7    0.12       1.2    0.32       3.2    0.52
5 gender_m             2.5    0.02       2.5    0.22       3.5    0.52
6 gender_f             3.6    0.38       1.6    0.18       0.6    0.15
7 last_element         4      0.28       2.3    0.08       5      0.48
```

Since I typically work with tidyverse, I would particularly appreciate solutions that use these packages (probably dplyr or purrr?).

### EDIT:

I thought there would be an elegant way to do this using map(). Maybe there is but I haven't found it yet. For the mean time, I figured out a way that simply restructures the data into an appropriate long format and then computes the statistics.

```
df %>% 
  # all grouping vars need to be of the same type, here "factor" is most appropriate
  mutate_at(grouping_vars, list(factor)) %>%
  # pivot longer, so that each row is a unique combination of grouping variable and grouping level
  pivot_longer(
    cols = one_of(grouping_vars), 
    names_to = "group_var",
    values_to = "group_level"
  ) %>% 
  # merge grouping variable and group level into a single column 
  unite(var_level,group_var,group_level, sep="_") %>% 
  # group by group level
  group_by(var_level) %>% 
  # compute means and sd for each test variable
  summarise_at(test_vars,  list(~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

The result seems fine, e.g., the mean of var1 of the two people who live in London (2.2 + 4.5) is 3.35.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   var_level    var1_mean var2_mean var3_mean var1_sd var2_sd var3_sd
   <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 education_1       2.65      3.15      0.15   0.636   1.48   0.0707
 2 education_2       4.5       2.5       3.5   NA      NA     NA     
 3 education_3       1.65      2.65      3.65   0.919   1.91   0.919 
 4 education_5       3.2       4.7       3.7    2.55    0.424  1.84  
 5 gender_f          2.72      2.48      2.72   1.47    1.13   1.83  
 6 gender_m          2.87      4.53      2.53   1.89    0.416  2.40  
 7 place_London      3.35      3.35      1.85   1.63    1.20   2.33  
 8 place_Madrid      1.85      2.85      3.35   0.636   2.19   1.34  
 9 place_Paris       3.1       2.1       0.1   NA      NA     NA     
10 place_Rome        3         4.5       4      2.83    0.707  1.41
```

**Any thoughts on possible risks of this approach or how this could be improved?**

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question with some expected output?

Answer (score 3):

One option is the `describeBy` function from `psych`:

```
library(psych)
describeBy(df,group = c("gender","education"), mat= TRUE)
```

Then subset what you want from there.

---

Another, surprisingly simple option with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
group.vars <- c("gender","education")
measure.vars <- c("var1","var2")

df %>% 
  group_by_at(group.vars) %>%
  summarize_at(measure.vars,
                      list(mean =~ mean(.),sd =~ sd(.)))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   gender [2]
  gender education var1_mean var2_mean var1_sd var2_sd
  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 f              1      3.1       2.1   NA      NA    
2 f              2      4.5       2.5   NA      NA    
3 f              3      1.65      2.65   0.919   1.91 
4 m              1      2.2       4.2   NA      NA    
5 m              5      3.2       4.7    2.55    0.424
```

You can continue adding additional function to that list. For every element, the name will be appended to the variable and the result will be come the column values. Recall that `~` is shorthand for `function(x)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. These solutions return a dataframe that shows M and SD for combinations of group levels. I think I didn't phrase my question clearly enough (now updated).